# Как спарсить динамическую часть сайта

Tags: java, html

Нужно спарсить с сайта стима это число, что на скриншоте, но проблема в том, что при парсинге html кода с помощью jsoup, этого числа там нету, т.к. поидее оно подгружается динамически. Как можно вытащить это число? https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Driver%20Gloves%20%7C%20Racing%20Green%20%28Well-Worn%29 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Способов много, но к сожалению, зачастую спарсить какой-то контент дороже самого контента.

1) [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/)

2) [Content Downloader X1](http://?p=600)

3) [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/)